# Using excess video memory for disk caching?

Tags: linux, video, cache, bsd, caching

On newer Ryzen 5000-based laptops, the integrated graphics controller always gets at least 1GB of shared video memory. In the BIOS settings, 1GB is the minimum. For people who don't need 1GB for video stuff because they use 2D graphics mainly, is there a way to grab some of that shared video memory and let the Linux or BSD kernel use it for disk file caching?

Comment: can you post output of glxinfo -B ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That memory is pinned for communication with the GPU, and can't be simply repurposed by the OS.

And you have the classical misconception that 2D application graphics don't need much memory. GPUs these days are used for compositing, meaning that everything you see in a browser, your Xemacs, or any other window, is actually held (and computed!) in GPU RAM. You switching between windows usually only means that X.org tells your GPU to "hey, you have this texture in your RAM, please put that in front now". Not to mention that your browser (assuming it's firefox or chromium) lets the GPU calculate what you see on screen. Which means the whole of all pages currently open (and not already retired to be re-calculated on demand, which happens to very old tabs) are held in their entirety in GPU RAM – not just the visible part.

Just to illustrate: I have two screens, with maybe a dozen terminal (alacritty) windows open, 6 open PDFs, 22 firefox tabs, one chat program and a file manager window: It's eating nearly 2 GB of GPU RAM.

Don't know the support of your GPU, and your drivers, for video decoding, but consider that it takes GPU RAM as well.

So, all in all, even if it was technical possible (it's not) to take that RAM away from the GPU, you would be doing yourself a disservice, probably, because things that are quickly computed by the GPU in that RAM would have to be slowly (and less power-efficiently!) computed by your CPU in the user-available RAM. Especially on a laptop, that sounds like a pretty bad idea!

Comment: You can under Windows: https://github.com/prsyahmi/GpuRamDrive It must be even simpler under Linux. And that compositing you're talking about? I know have Firefox with a dozen tabs open and I'm under 400MB of GPU RAM.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov hehehe. lol, CUDA DMA buffers, that's one way of enabling such insanity :D You could write the same for Linux, but just like that windows software, it would only offer a userland-implemented file system, not a filesystem buffer for the VFS layer.

Comment: I see no issues in creating a block device using VRAM which means a very real disk device. No one has bothered for some reasons: Windows continues to be a much more user-friendly OS than Linux despite Linux being open.

Comment: The real issue however is that I've no idea how to make the kernel use VRAM only for disk caching. The Linux kernel AFAIK doesn't allow to partition virtual RAM. Every RAM page could be used for running applications or disk cache.

Comment: but a block device is not what OP is asking for – they ask for backing memory for file caching!

Comment: There's https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/caching/netfs-api.html but I've no idea how to use/apply it.

Comment: Exaclty! It's hard to integrate memory as caches. Windows doesn't make adding any memory region as cache memory not any easier – note that GpuRamDrive only does what you could hack together in a few lines of userland code just as well under Linux, a block device backed by some memory region. (Userland, because you need to deal with nvidia's userland driver interface to request such a memory region, nvidia cowardly hides these APIs)

Comment: by the way, your link is good, but you'd rather want to read https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/caching/backend-api.html , which explains how you can add a caching backend. But the whole userland memory / kernel-side caching is going to be a nightmare, both security-wise and from a "oh, yeah, somehow the userland application quit, now my cache with all the uncommitted data is gone" data safety point of view.

Comment: I should point out that my main (Linux) computer for 2 years now has been the Raspberry pi 4 8GB, which I've given only 64 MB or so for the shared video memory, and Firefox etc work just fine. I suppose I could try giving it more to see if performance speeds up, but IIRC the Rpi foundation folks discourage bothering with that.

Comment: yeah, the GPU on the RPi4 isn't going to do much for you, anyway. (drivers super proprietary, no comparable support etc). Point is more that memory you take away from the GPU is not that unlikely to end up being used in your main RAM :)